# Extended unpacking not creating separate items in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I am executing the below code:

```
s = 'python'
a, b, *c, d = s[0], s[1], s[2:-1], s[-1]
print(c)
```

I am getting output as `['tho']`

Please help me understand why the output is not `['t', 'h', 'o']` ?

As we are using the `* operator` on LHS, so the output should be `['t', 'h', 'o']` and not `['tho']`

Comment: `a, b, *c, d = s[0], s[1], *s[2:-1], s[-1]`

Comment: It's working as expected. You're getting the substring as third item, put into c collection. One item.

Comment: Why would it be? You have four items on the right, four variables on the left. `*c` isn’t unpacking the value of the items, it takes as many items from the right so that the remaining can be cleanly assigned to the other three variables.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to unpack the string as well, else there is only a single element (`'tho'`):

```
s = 'python'
a, b, *c, d = s[0], s[1], *s[2:-1], s[-1]
print(c)
```

Output: `['t', 'h', 'o']`

I this what you were looking for is:

```
a,b,*c,d = s
print(c)
```

where unpacking really makes sense

Answer (score 1):

It's because `s[2:-1]` is not unpacked. There is no reason for it to unpack.

You need:

```
a, b, *c, d = s[0], s[1], *s[2:-1], s[-1]
```

Unpack assignments will only unpack into one sequence of multiple values when there are multiple non-attached values, like `'t', 'h', 'o'`, not when the value is `'tho'`.

---

Now:

```
print(c)
```

Is:

```
['t', 'h', 'o']
```